# Why am I getting a Next.js cookie error when accessing over `0.0.0.0` but not over `localhost`

Tags: node.js, next.js, next.js13

**Disclaimer: I'm new to Next.js and React (Historically a Vue developer) and not super confident in the aspects of Node as they differ from browser JS yet.**

---

I run my code either via `npm run` OR after building and `start`ing it OR after building it into a container image using the canonical Next.js Dockerfile verbatim.

When I do, if I access it over `localhost`, everything works fine. When I access it over the external interface (`0.0.0.0`), I get the following error:

`Cookies can only be modified in a Server Action or Route Handler.`

To be clear, I'm running the application **one time**. It exposes itself on both interfaces at once so there is no difference in the way I'm running it.

---

My code looks roughly like this:

```
"use server";

import { cookies } from "next/headers";

export default async function Page() {
  const cookieStore = cookies();

  cookieStore.set("anything", "something");

  // I don't think the rest matters
}
```

I admit that I'm struggling with the notion of "ServerActions." The docs suggest that a "ServerAction" is an async function defined in a module that runs on the server (which I take to mean it doesn't need `"use client"`). As such, I could still be doing something wrong making the error message accurate.

But why would I only get this error over the external interface and not over `localhost`?

Comment: i dont think u can set cookies on 0.0.0.0

Comment: Can you elaborate on that, @DarrenZou? Is that a React thing or something about webservers that I'm not aware of.

Comment: not sure, but this post tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669289/setting-a-cookie-domain-to-an-ip-address-using-cors